# Include session on server for assets but prevent session Cookie header from being sent for assets

Tags: php, session-cookies

Someone recently pointed out that the asset files were also sending the session `Cookie` header, not necessary. I would like to access a few arrays/variables stored in `$_SESSION` in some of the asset files though without having the `Cookie` header be sent to the client for those asset files.

In the asset files (e.g. like JavaScript) I simply include the `session.php` file. Since the client initializes the HTTP request to the asset files this is not simply passing `$_SESSION` as a parameter.

How do I initialize and access `$_SESSION` though not have it's associated `Cookie` header sent for asset files?

I can obviously determine how to combine `substr` with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to determine if the request is for an asset (e.g. `*.js`) and all asset files have proper file extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!headers_sent()) {header_remove('set-cookie');}
```

Comment: Does this work? I was going to suggest a solution with `ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);`

Comment: @ArSeN I posted it as the answer so yes, it works. The file itself still has access to `$_SESSION` though the header (being already set by that point) is simply removed *presuming* the headers have obviously not been sent.